# Block geolocation request to wait for user's response

Tags: cefsharp

I'm implementing, in my **WinForms** CefSharp app, the **IGeolocationHandler**, as explained in the example [here](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Handlers/GeolocationHandler.cs#L12). I would like to display a custom panel to ask the user permission (the reason I don't use MessageBox is that I have to show multiple options), but I can't find a way to make the handler wait for the user response.

Creating a public event in the main form (*Home.vb*) and adding an *AddHandler* to the handler does not help. Using **TaskCompletionSource** does not work because I can't make **OnRequestGeolocationPermission** async, and polling a public variable causes the handler to always return false.

Does everyone know a way to do it?

Thanks a lot

Comment: You need to use the `callback`. basically most handlers work the same, `return true` means you'd like to handle the request. When your done, execute the callback (if you never execute the callback, make sure you call `Dispose` as it's a `unmanaged` wrapper and will leak memory (small leak).

Comment: Thanks for your response, amaitland, but, since I were unable to make my custom "Geolocation asking" working, I decided to use a MsgBox, requesting Yes or No. When I click on Yes or on No, my application crashes and I believe this is a CefSharp problem. Any idea? _—PWhite_

Comment: Execute your message box on the `UI` thread. If you require assistance, you'd need to post a `stacktrace`, just saying it crashes it pretty useless.

Comment: Also make sure you've set the relevant `Google API Keys`

Comment: https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.Wpf.Example/Handlers/GeolocationHandler.cs#L12

Comment: The relevant API keys are set correctly with `Environment.SetEnvironmentVariable`, but I can't see any errors nor exceptions, only the Windows' message "The application has stopped working".

Comment: Also, I'm using this [example](https://github.com/cefsharp/CefSharp/blob/master/CefSharp.WinForms.Example/Handlers/GeolocationHandler.cs#L12) since my app is WinForms.

Comment: **UPDATE**: trying the code in the example again, the app crashes only if "No" is selected, so with `callback.Continue(false)` and `Return False`.

Comment: If your using the `callback`, then always `return true;`

Comment: The `WinForms` example probably should be updated. Feel free to submit a `PR` when you have something working.